# FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION video

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm having an black screen/freezing error on my application that I'm unable to solve. So I did a small application that plays two videos in loop to try to reproduce the error. I sucessfully did.

The error from the Android Log is this:

```
08-26 06:04:12.426 D/CDX_Player(   90): >>>>>>>> CedarX Player Version: 00010707
08-26 06:04:12.426 I/CedarPlayerWrapper(   90): setDataSource('/mnt/sdcard/cman/video1.mp4')
08-26 06:04:12.426 I/WindowManager(  156): MediaPlayer.isPlayingVideo
08-26 06:04:12.526 D/osal_linux(   90): init hw ref count:1
08-26 06:04:12.536 D/MediaPlayer(14489): getMetadata
08-26 06:04:12.546 D/VideoDec_Component(   90): vdec touch cpu freq
08-26 06:04:12.566 D/AudioDec_Component(   90): touch cpu freq
08-26 06:04:12.606 D/SurfaceTextureClient(   90): dispatchSetBuffersGeometry1!
08-26 06:04:12.606 D/SurfaceTextureClient(   90): dispatchSetBuffersGeometry2!
08-26 06:04:12.606 D/        (   90): layer_info.w = 1280
08-26 06:04:12.606 D/        (   90): layer_info.h = 720
08-26 06:04:12.606 D/        (   90): layer_info.format = 86
08-26 06:04:12.606 D/        (   90): layer_info.screenid = 0
08-26 06:04:12.606 D/        (   87): layer_info.w = 1280
08-26 06:04:12.606 D/        (   87): layer_info.h = 720
08-26 06:04:12.606 D/        (   87): layer_info.format = 86
08-26 06:04:12.606 D/        (   87): layer_info.screenid = 0
08-26 06:04:12.616 I/hwcomposer(   87): layer open hdl:101,ret :0
08-26 06:04:15.636 D/AudioDec_Component(   90): touch cpu freq
08-26 06:04:15.996 D/AudioDec_Component(   90): touch cpu freq
08-26 06:04:17.026 D/AudioDec_Component(   90): touch cpu freq
08-26 06:04:17.536 W/mov_parser(   90): retrun read finish
08-26 06:04:17.536 E/mov_parser_oal(   90): Try to read sample failed!
08-26 06:04:17.536 W/mov_parser(   90): retrun read finish
08-26 06:04:17.536 E/mov_parser_oal(   90): Try to read sample failed!
08-26 06:04:19.476 D/VideoDec_Component(   90): vdec touch cpu freq
08-26 06:04:19.486 D/CedarXPlayer(   90): MEDIA_PLAYBACK_COMPLETE
08-26 06:04:19.496 W/MediaPlayer(14489): info/warning (702, 0)
08-26 06:04:19.496 I/MediaPlayer(14489): Info (702,0)
08-26 06:04:19.596 D/osal_linux(   90): exit hw ref count:0
08-26 06:04:19.596 D/CDX_Player(   90): >>>>>>>> CedarX Player Version: 00010707
08-26 06:04:19.596 I/CedarPlayerWrapper(   90): setDataSource('/mnt/sdcard/cman/video2.wmv')
08-26 06:04:19.606 I/WindowManager(  156): MediaPlayer.isPlayingVideo
08-26 06:04:19.656 D/osal_linux(   90): init hw ref count:1
08-26 06:04:19.676 D/MediaPlayer(14489): getMetadata
08-26 06:04:19.676 D/VideoDec_Component(   90): vdec touch cpu freq
08-26 06:04:19.686 E/JavaBinder(14489): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
08-26 06:04:19.696 D/SurfaceTextureClient(   90): dispatchSetBuffersGeometry1!
08-26 06:04:19.696 D/SurfaceTextureClient(   90): dispatchSetBuffersGeometry2!
08-26 06:04:19.696 D/        (   90): layer_info.w = 1280
08-26 06:04:19.696 D/        (   90): layer_info.h = 720
08-26 06:04:19.696 D/        (   90): layer_info.format = 86
08-26 06:04:19.696 D/        (   90): layer_info.screenid = 0
08-26 06:04:19.696 D/        (   87): layer_info.w = 1280
08-26 06:04:19.696 D/        (   87): layer_info.h = 720
08-26 06:04:19.696 D/        (   87): layer_info.format = 86
08-26 06:04:19.696 D/        (   87): layer_info.screenid = 0
08-26 06:04:19.736 I/hwcomposer(   87): layer open hdl:101,ret :0
08-26 06:04:19.766 D/AudioDec_Component(   90): touch cpu freq
08-26 06:04:20.806 W/ThrottleService(  156): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
08-26 06:04:24.236 D/AudioDec_Component(   90): touch cpu freq
08-26 06:04:24.586 W/asf_parser(   90): data object error!
08-26 06:04:24.586 W/asf_parser_oal(   90): Try to read sample failed!
08-26 06:04:24.586 W/AudioDec_Component(   90): audiodec ret: -2
08-26 06:04:26.666 D/VideoDec_Component(   90): vdec touch cpu freq
08-26 06:04:26.676 D/CedarXPlayer(   90): MEDIA_PLAYBACK_COMPLETE
08-26 06:04:26.696 W/MediaPlayer(14489): info/warning (702, 0)
08-26 06:04:26.696 I/MediaPlayer(14489): Info (702,0)
08-26 06:04:57.846 D/dalvikvm(  224): GC_CONCURRENT freed 386K, 75% free 7848K/30279K, paused 2ms+5ms
08-26 06:08:18.156 D/dalvikvm(  224): GC_CONCURRENT freed 382K, 75% free 7851K/30279K, paused 2ms+4ms
08-26 06:08:40.536 D/dalvikvm(  156): GC_CONCURRENT freed 510K, 9% free 8946K/9735K, paused 2ms+5ms
08-26 06:10:41.816 I/EventLogService(  383): Aggregate from 1377510041773 (log), 1377510041773 (data)
08-26 06:11:44.456 D/dalvikvm(  224): GC_CONCURRENT freed 387K, 75% free 7850K/30279K, paused 2ms+6ms
08-26 06:14:20.806 W/ThrottleService(  156): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
08-26 06:15:23.786 D/dalvikvm(  224): GC_CONCURRENT freed 383K, 75% free 7851K/30279K, paused 2ms+5ms
08-26 06:17:50.136 D/dalvikvm(  156): GC_CONCURRENT freed 500K, 9% free 8938K/9735K, paused 2ms+5ms
08-26 06:18:46.096 D/dalvikvm(  224): GC_CONCURRENT freed 387K, 75% free 7850K/30279K, paused 2ms+4ms
```

The error from Application Output is this:

```
[MediaPlayer] getMetadata
[MediaPlayer] info/warning (702, 0)
[MediaPlayer] Info (702,0)
[MediaPlayer] getMetadata
[JavaBinder] !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
[MediaPlayer] info/warning (702, 0)
[MediaPlayer] Info (702,0)
```

I saw on the internet that may be the way I'm setting the video to play, that I should use SetURI, does that makes sense?

The code I use is this:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.IO;

namespace SimpleVideoPlayer
{
    [Activity (Label = "SimpleVideoPlayer", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity, Android.Media.MediaPlayer.IOnCompletionListener, Android.Media.MediaPlayer.IOnErrorListener
    {
        int flag = 1;
        string path1 = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, "cman/video1.mp4");
        string path2 = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, "cman/video2.wmv");
        VideoView videoView;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            RequestWindowFeature (WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
            Window.SetFlags (WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen, WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
            RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Landscape;  

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            videoView = FindViewById<VideoView> (Resource.Id.videoView1);

            // Seta esta classe como a classe a ser chamada quando o video acabar de ser executado
            videoView.SetOnCompletionListener (this);
            videoView.SetOnErrorListener (this);

            videoView.SetVideoPath (path1);
            videoView.Start ();
        }

        public void OnCompletion (Android.Media.MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            if (flag == 1) {

                videoView.SetVideoPath (path2);

                flag = 2;

                videoView.Start ();

            } else if (flag == 2) {

                videoView.SetVideoPath (path1);

                flag = 1;

                videoView.Start ();
            }
        }

        public bool OnError (Android.Media.MediaPlayer mp, Android.Media.MediaError what, int extra)
        {


            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The layout is pretty simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <VideoView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/videoView1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you so much.

Regards,

Igor Guerra

Answer (score 0):

Add this listener for your videoview object

```
videoView.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);
```

infoListener will be something like this:

```
    private OnInfoListener infoListener = new OnInfoListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

                if(what==702 && extra == 0 && !mp.isPlaying()){

                    videoView.stopPlayback();
                    videoView = null;

                    // Now reinitialise the videoView and setVideoPath(String) and then start() again

                }
                return true;
            }
     };
```